# How to use jenkins app center plugin with dynamic version number

Tags: jenkins, visual-studio-app-center

I have a standard jenkins job (it's not a pipeline) that uses the [jenkins appcenter plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/appcenter) to upload the resulting app to appcenter. The version number of the app is determined while the job is running (incorporating the jenkins `$BUILD_NUMBER` value).

The plugin has a field called `Path to App` with this description:

```
Relative path to app. Supports variable substitution.

For example: three/days/xiola.apk or three/days/${APP}.apk
```

Sounds great but I don't know how to make it work with a variable that is set while the jenkins job is running. In other words I don't know how to set a variable called `${APP}` that would make the line in their example work. If I just declare a variable in a shell script like this:

```
export APP=1.2.${BUILD_NUMBER}
```

it doesn't work. The plugin doesn't have access to the value. I'm guessing that variables like these disappear after the shell script ends.

It will accept environment variables or job parameters but those are read only so I can't set them inside the job.

How can I do this? If I can just declare a variable that any part of the jenkins job can see I think it would work. But is there such a thing?